# Detect if a folder is a clouded folder

Tags: c++

Is there a way to check and find all in once all clouded folder that are on a computer without enumerate all possibilities ?

What I need is : I take a path and it tells me if it's a clouded folder.

Example : I use Google Drive, OneDrive, DropBox, and other. I would like to know if it's one of them without having to enumerate all possibilities of each services like :

- Onedrive can be check on registry and have "Drive" on his path;
- Google Drive have a .ini file on root folder and have "Drive" on his path;
- DropBox have a file on root folder (I think) ;

Can't find the magic solution that check all services that exists.
Is there a secret tag or info hidden on folder saying "I'm related to a cloud service" ?

Can't found nothing about it :(
I've checked GetDriveTypeW but OneDrive and GoogleDrive are detect as fixed drive (and it's normal) and FILE_REMOTE_PROTOCOL_INFO but no sign of answer there either..

Please help !

Thanks.

Comment: How does "How do I detect if a folder represents a folder hosted on a cloud service?" sound for a title?

Comment: This question, hasn't earned the C++ tag, IMO.  There's no sign of C++ being relevant here yet.

Comment: Some cloud provider (I know owncloud does so) create a drive where the files can be downloaded full transparent to all applications. I should be possible to detect such folders. It is called something like Virtual File System.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're out of luck this time.  I don't believe there is anything fundamental in the Windows operating system or filesystem that tells you if an application installed on the system is mirroring or otherwise syncing files and folders.  There is no magic bullet, to the best of my knowledge.

You'll have to tackle these on an application-by-application basis using awareness of each type of service and which folders it is syncing as you are currently doing.

Comment: This is the conclusion I had drawn from my research. But I wanted to ask just in case! Thanks for your answer.